# Cannot go beyond 27 decimal places with decimal module

Tags: python, decimal, digit

Can anyone tell me why going beyond 27 decimal places results in a TypeError? I've looked at the official documentation, but don't see an answer to that. Error message mentions float, but I don't see any float in the code. I specifically got rid of all floats.

```
Evaluate number e to n significant digits (up to 27): 28
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex6.py", line 20, in <module>
    while (deci.Decimal(1) / deci.Decimal((math.factorial(step)))) >     deci.Decimal(eval(sigdig2)):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'Decimal' and 'float'
```

>

```
# imports necessary modules

import math
import decimal as deci

# defines variables

eul = 0
step = 0

# queries for input

sigdig = int(raw_input("Evaluate number e to n significant digits (up to 27): "))
sigdig2 = 'deci.Decimal(1)/' + str(deci.Decimal(10) ** deci.Decimal(sigdig))

deci.getcontext().prec = (sigdig + 1)

# evaluates e

while (deci.Decimal(1) / deci.Decimal((math.factorial(step)))) > deci.Decimal(eval(sigdig2)):
    eul += (deci.Decimal(1) / deci.Decimal((math.factorial(step))))
    step +=1

#prints the result

print
printer = '"e = %.' + str(sigdig) + 'f" % (eul)'
print eval(printer)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> str(decimal.Decimal(10) ** 28)
'1.000000000000000000000000000E+28'  # <- not a decimal
>>> str(decimal.Decimal(10) ** 27)
'1000000000000000000000000000'     # <- also not a decimal, but Decimal/int is defined
```

This is why you don't use `eval` :)

Without `eval`:

```
import math
import decimal as deci

# defines variables

eul = 0
step = 0

# queries for input

sigdig = int(raw_input("Evaluate number e to n significant digits (up to 27): "))
sigdig2 = deci.Decimal(1) / deci.Decimal(10 ** sigdig)

deci.getcontext().prec = (sigdig + 1)

# evaluates e

while deci.Decimal(1) / deci.Decimal(math.factorial(step)) > sigdig2:
    eul += deci.Decimal(1) / deci.Decimal(math.factorial(step))
    step +=1

#prints the result

print
print 'e = %s' % eul
```

```
$ python e.py
Evaluate number e to n significant digits (up to 27): 40

e = 2.7182818284590450907955982984276488423347

Evaluate number e to n significant digits (up to 27): 1000

e = 2.71828182845904523536028747135266249775724709369995957496696762772407663035
35475945713821785251664274274663919320030599218174135966290435729003342952605956
30738132328627943490763233829880753195251019011573834187930702154089149934884167
50924476146066808226480016847741185374234544243710753907774499206955170276183860
62613313845830007520449338265602976067371132007093287091274437470472306969772093
10141692836819025515108657463772111252389784425056953696770785449969967946864454
90598793163688923009879312773617821542499922957635148220826989519366803318252886
93984964651058209392398294887933203625094431173012381970684161403970198376793206
83282376464804295311802328782509819455815301756717361332069811250996181881593041
69035159888851934580727386673858942287922849989208680582574927961048419844436346
32449684875602336248270419786232090021609902353043699418491463140934317381436405
46253152096183690888707016768396424378140592714563549061303107208510383750510115
7477041718986106873969655212671546889570350362
```

Comment: nice catch. +1 on the evil eval.

Comment: Thanks, yes, it works much better. Is it possible to go beyond 51 decimals?

Comment: Sure, just not with `printf`-like formatting. Just `print eul` at the end. Edited my code.

Comment: It turns out only 15 decimal places are correct. What can be the reason? I'm talking about the code without eval in it.

Comment: Works, thanks. I added that ev(a/i)l print work-around because it would round up at the nearest 0.

Comment: Not sure I follow. What sign? All terms are positive. Alternating series is equal to 1/e, not e.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. It seems everything is correct but the last few digits? E.g., of the 1000 digits the last 2 are incorrect.

Comment: Yes, not sure why those digits are incorrect. I did a work-around. I changed deci.getcontext().prec to (sigdig + 2) and I simply print print "e =", str(eul)[:-1]. They were incorrect even for 20 decimals. Not sure what causes it.

Comment: Are you good with calculus and acquainted with physical chemistry? I have another application I coded in October. It evaluates the concentration of reagents in A->B->C->... consecutive reactions. Normally it would require solving a heterogeneous linear differential equation at each step. I came up with an algorithm building that construes the function of concentration in time for each reagent. It uses eval and (floating point) at its core. Maybe you could take a look and see whether there's a work-around for this, because when the kinetic constants are differ only a bit, the plot messes up.

Comment: Well, craft another question and we'll see. At least we'll spot if anything is wrong in python.

Comment: The use of math.factorial is causing your precision problem. It only calculates results to ~16 digits of precision. Instead of calculating math.factorial(step) for each iteration, add another value fact that is set to one and is multiplied by step each iteration.

Comment: There's no precision problem in the current code. I've checked 5000 digits. They are all correct.

Comment: It turns out that math.factorial actually calculates an exact integer value so my comment was incorrect. However, it is always risky to use the math module and Decimal instances at the same time since most of the functions in the math module only return ~16 digits of precision.

Comment: Here's another problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15177354/enforcing-the-number-of-decimal-places-when-printing-results The exercises from the textbook I'm doing are simple (I'm just a beginner), but I've modified them considerably to be challenging.